# How to use interruptions?

Tags: c, interrupt, led, stm32f4discovery

I like to make a little program for my st32f4discovery. It should blink an LED, but not with delays, it should interrupt the LED, so that the interruption make the LED blink.

Is anyone familiar with the st32f4discovery? I cant find a working tutorial in the web.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a timer and configure it to generate an interrupt when it reaches a specific value. Roughly the steps to follow are:

1. Activate the clock for your timer
2. Configure and activate your timer
3. Configure the interrupt priority and activate the interrupt which will be generated by your timer
4. In the timer interrupt handler, toggle your LED state

Did you have a look at the stm32F4x standard peripheral library from ST? There are many code examples which would help you to achieve what you want to do. It is available
[here](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF257901).

Unfortunately the ST website links changes all the time, but you can find the library by googling for STM32F4 series, then click on any CPU from the STM32F4 family on the ST website, go on "Design Resources" and amoung the resources is a link to the library.